# how to create an anonymous int array for the purpose of passing as a parameter

Tags: java, arrays, int, anonymous-types

I need to create anonymous int array to be passed to a method. I don't want to declare a variable and then pass the variable because it makes code look crowded.
This is what we can do for Integer array.

```
new Box(new Integer[]{1,2,3});
```

how to do that with int?

Comment: `new Box(new int[]{1,2,3});` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do:

```
new Box(new int[]{1,2,3});
```

Comment: funny why eclipse marked it as error the first time i tried. now it works. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you already know about array contents, you can always employ the following methodology

```
public void foo(int... args) {
    for (int arg : args) {
      // do smth with arg.
     }
}


foo(1,2,3,4,5,6,7); //pretty much unlimited arguments can be passed in.


//or you can do the same to a class constructor as well
new Box(1,2,3,4,5,6);

class Box {
  public Box(int... args){
    //loop 
  }
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: would this work if i had to send multiple int array parameters? like new Box(intarray, intarray);

Answer (score 0):

ok. it seems its same as the question.

```
new Box(new int[]{1,2,3});
```

not sure why eclipse gave me the squiggly red bar before.